# How select a grouping of matching values from a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given the following table structure:

```
create table SiteFeatures (
    Feature nvarchar(255),
    SiteUrl nvarchar(255)
)
```

And the following example data:

```
Feature     SiteUrl
Feature1    /sites/a/
Feature1    /sites/a/l/
Feature2    /sites/a/l/
Feature3    /sites/a/l/
Feature4    /sites/a/l/rd/
Feature5    /sites/a/l/rd/
Feature6    /sites/a/l/rd/
Feature1    /sites/a/pa/
Feature2    /sites/a/pa/
Feature3    /sites/a/pa/
Feature4    /sites/a/pa/rd/
Feature5    /sites/a/pa/rd/
Feature6    /sites/a/pa/rd/
Feature4    /sites/a/s/rd/
Feature5    /sites/a/s/rd/
Feature6    /sites/a/s/rd/
Feature1    /sites/a/s/
Feature2    /sites/a/s/
Feature3    /sites/a/s/
```

I want to retrieve each unique grouping of Features (and ideally the corresponding sites which these features are mapped to). Given the example data above the "groupings" I want returned would be:

```
Feature1
Feature1, Feature2, Feature3
Feature4, Feature5
```

And if with the corresponding sites then:

```
Feature1 = /sites/a/
Feature1,Feature2,Feature3 = /sites/a/l/, /sites/a/pa/, /sites/a/s/
Feature4,Feature5,Feature6 = /sites/a/l/rd/, /sites/a/pa/rd/, /sites/a/s/rd/
```

I am not too concerned with the format of the returned results just as long as I have the required groups/relationships returned.

Is it possible to do this in sql?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you running?

Comment: I think you want to look into using Pivot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on SQL 2005 or higher,  you could try:

```
select distinct
(
    STUFF 
    (
        (
            SELECT ',' + Feature
            FROM SiteFeatures t2
            WHERE  t1.SiteUrl = t2.SiteUrl
            ORDER BY Feature
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT
        ).value('root[1]','nvarchar(max)')
        ,1,1,''
    )
) as chars
from SiteFeatures t1;
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked well. Do you mind breaking down each command so I can understand how that works? When i tried to split it up into individual components it wouldn't run (eg. seperating the STUFF out and then trying the FOR XML etc...).

Comment: The trickiest part or breaking the structure down is the fact that xml value attribute turns a single cell into a table. I reformatted the answer to show the nesting.